# trying to include a specific branch of a package not on packagist

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to use a specific branch of repo but getting an error:

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "programmingarehard/arbiter",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Convenience library to manipulate Symfony ACL's",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "David Adams",
            "email": "adams.david.10@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ProgrammingAreHard\\Arbiter\\": "src",
            "ProgrammingAreHard\\Arbiter\\Spec\\": "spec"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/security": "2.4.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "bestform/phpspec": "dev-psr4-support"
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "vendor/bin"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/bestform/phpspec"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0.x-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)           Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
    Problem 1
    - The requested package bestform/phpspec could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.   Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.   Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

[This](https://github.com/bestform/phpspec/tree/psr4-support) is the repo/branch i'm trying to pull into my package. Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository you are using does not contain a software named `bestform/phpspec`. Look at the composer.json that is in there, and use the value given as "name". Its `phpspec/phpspec`, and any branch will only ever be found if you use that name.

The name of the Github repository is irrelevant. Don't confuse it with the "composer" name.